# Charles proxy doesn't work even after installing the root certificate on iphone device

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

Here's what I did so far:
1. Install Charles on my mac
2. Connect mac and iPhone to same WiFi network
3. Charles->Proxy->SSL Proxy Settings. Enable for *
4. Charles->Help->Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device
5. Configure iPhone to proxy to IP provided in step 3.
6. on iPhone, went to chls.pro/ssl and installed root certificate.

The iPhone web traffic shows in Charles, but is still ssl encrypted. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to General->About->Certificate Trust Settings and enable full trust for the Charles Proxy certificate.

Comment: even after doing so, for some app. it just  show the error that the certificate on client is not trusted. how to overcome it?

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode the app is probably pinning the server's certificate in which case using a MITM approach such as Charles will not work as the application's code has been set to reject certificates that aren't pinned (like the certs vended by the Charles CA).